# bootstrap navbar collapse is white when toggled

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I've got a semi-transparent navbar in bootstrap but when the screen size breaks down and goes to the "mobile" view when toggled it pushes the content down and leaves the top of the page with a white background.

Here's my code:

**HTML**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-custom" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#AboutMe">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#ContactMe">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
.navbar-custom {
    background-color: rgba(240, 240, 240, 0.3);
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a, .navbar-custom .navbar-brand {
    color: black;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
    color: black;
    background-color: rgba(240, 240, 240, 0.3);
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 766px) {
    .collapsing, .in {
        background-color:rgba(240, 240, 240, 0.3)!important;
    }
    .collapsing ul li a, .in ul li a {
        color: black!important;
    }
    .collapsing ul li a:hover, .in ul li a:hover {
        color: white!important;
    }
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-toggle {
    border-color:black;
}
.navbar-custom .icon-bar {
    background-color:black;
}
```

I've tried altering the `position` and `z-index` but none of it seems to work and is there a simpler or different way to achieve what I've done?

[Here's my codepen.](http://codepen.io/caesar9/pen/bVPNvj)

Comment: Please format your code appropriately.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still learning and rushed it as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, the green background is on the `#container1` element. When the navigation menu collapses/expands on mobile devices, it pushes the `#container1` element down (which means that the navigation menu no longer has a green background behind it).

I'd suggest absolutely positioning the navigation menu over the `#container1` element, and then adding padding to account for the height of the menu.

[**Updated Example**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JYQowR)

```
.navbar-custom {
  background-color: rgba(240, 240, 240, 0.3);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Alternatively, you could avoid absolute positioning, and just set the background on the `body` element (which will always be behind the navigation menu).

Comment: Thank you, that works great. Another lesson learned as a newbie.

Comment: I also had the bootstrap.css after my own .css rather than before so when I altered the position in my css it didn't work. Again more newbie mistakes I won't be repeating.

Answer (score 1):

That happens because you set `background-color: green` to #container1, so html and body will still have a white background-color.
Add to your css

```
html {background-color: green}
```